# JSONStore difference between 'number' and 'integer' in searchFields

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I have a question about JSONStore searchFields.

If I use `number` as the searchFields key and try to find data by `WL.JSONStore.find` method with `0` as the query, It will hit all data (not filtered).

With the `integer` of the case above works fine.

What's the difference between `number` and `integer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSONStore uses SQLite to persist data, you can read about SQLite Data Types [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). The short answer is `number` will store data as `REAL` while `integer` will store data as `INTEGER`.

If you create a collection called `nums` with one searchField called `num` of type `number`

```
var nums = WL.JSONStore.initCollection('nums', {num: 'number'}, {});
```

and add some data:

```
var len = 5;
while (len--) {
    nums.add({num: len});
}
```

then call `find` with the query: `{num: 0}`

```
nums.find({num: 0}, {onSuccess: function (res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
}})
```

you should get back:

```
[{"_id":1,"json":{"num":4}},{"_id":2,"json":{"num":3}},{"_id":3,"json":{"num":2}},{"_id":4,"json":{"num":1}},{"_id":5,"json":{"num":0}}]
```

Notice that you got back all the documents you stored (num = 4, 3, 2, 1, 0).

If you look at the .sqlite file:

```
$ cd ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/[id]/Documents
$ sqlite3 jsonstore.sqlite
```

(The android file should be under `/data/data/com.[app-name]/databases/`)

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE nums ( _id INTEGER primary key autoincrement,  'num' REAL, json BLOB, _dirty REAL default 0, _deleted INTEGER default 0, _operation TEXT);
```

Notice the data type for num is `REAL`.

Running a query the same query used in the find function:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM nums WHERE num LIKE '%0%';
1|4.0|{"num":4}|1363326259.80431|0|add
2|3.0|{"num":3}|1363326259.80748|0|add
3|2.0|{"num":2}|1363326259.81|0|add
4|1.0|{"num":1}|1363326259.81289|0|add
5|0.0|{"num":0}|1363326259.81519|0|add
```

Notice `4` is stored as `4.0` and JSONStore's queries always use `LIKE`, any num with a `0` will match the query.

If you use `integer` instead:

```
var nums = WL.JSONStore.initCollection('nums', {num: 'integer'}, {});
```

Find returns:

```
[{"_id":5,"json":{"num":0}}]
```

The `schema` shows that num has an `INTEGER` data type:

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE nums ( _id INTEGER primary key autoincrement,  'num' INTEGER, json BLOB, _dirty REAL default 0, _deleted INTEGER default 0, _operation TEXT);

sqlite> SELECT * FROM nums WHERE num LIKE '%0%';
5|0|{"num":0}|1363326923.44466|0|add
```

I skipped some of the `onSuccess` and all the `onFailure` callbacks for brevity.

Comment: Using `LIKE`... It means even if I use `integer` data type and store data like `4, 44, 444`, then search by `4` will hit all of 3 data right? big problem..

Comment: "[...]then search by 4 will hit all of 3 data right?" Yes. As a side note: `findById(4)` will do an exact match on the `_id` field and return only one result.

Comment: OK. Only `findById()` will do an exact match. Thanks for your answers. I will request IBM to change the default SQL to not using `LIKE`.

Comment: @user2109809 if I answered your question, can you mark this answer as approved? (the green checkmark below the votes)

Answer (score 1):

The actual difference between a JSON number and integer is

```
defining {age: 'number'} indexes 1 as 1.0,
while defining{age: 'integer'} indexes 1 as 1.
```

Hope you understand