# IBM Worklight - JSONStore is not working when trying to push the data to back end server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

We are trying to push the data from IBM worklight application using JSONStore functionality.

We are working on IBM Worklight V5.0.6 environment.
Steps to reproduce:

1. Open Worklight 5.0.6 studio
2. import
   'module_07_11_JSONStore_with_Sync' project into workspace
3. Accept
   to migrate the project to latest Worklight version
4. Build & deploy
   the app to Worklight server
5. Try to create JSONStore
6. At this stage we are getting the error:

   > `JsonStoreWizard.InvokeProcedurePage` got exception invoking adapter

Because of this, we are not able to create a new JSONStore instance.

What is the reason for getting this error?

Comment: Did you try adapters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After:

> Accept to migrate the project to latest Worklight version

Expand the `adapters` folder > Right Click on the `user` folder > Select deploy Worklight Adapter and check it was deployed correctly in the console.

You may want to test the adapter in isolation too. "Invoke Adapter Procedure" from Eclipse.

There's no need to use the JSONStore Wizard to work with that sample, if I recall correctly. Just deploy the adapter, build all and deploy the app, open the Android or iPhone Worklight Application, play with the UI and read the source code.

I also recommend reading the [JSONStore documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_class_wl_jsonstore.html) especially the part under **Adapter**. Take a look at: [WL.JSONStore](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_class_wl_jsonstore.html), [init](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_init.html), [push](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_push.html), [load](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_load.html) and [count](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_count.html). The examples should help you get data and push it back to your adapter.

If you run into issues, [this StackOverflow answer can help you debug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15959984/186909) and provide more information if you ask JSONStore questions.

> What is the reason for getting this error?

The `JsonStoreWizard.InvokeProcedurePage` error seems to indicate invoking the adapter failed. Leave a comment if you're still unable to push data back and I'll probably update this answer.