# IBM WorkLight :Failed connect with offline data store

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I would like to create an application, where i have to use JSON STORE for offline data storage. So, please let me know how to work with JSON STORE.

Answer (score 4):

1. Read the [IBM Information Center JSONStore Documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_class_wl_jsonstore.html).
2. Read at least the following [IBM Worklight Getting Started Modules](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html):

   - JSONStore – The client-side JSON-based database overview
   - JSONStore – API basics
   - JSONStore – Synchronizing client and server databases **(if using Worklight Adapters)**
   - JSONStore – Encrypting sensitive data **(if using data encryption)**
   - Adapter framework overview **(if using Worklight Adapters)**
   - HTTP adapter – Communicating with HTTP back-end systems **(if using HTTP to get data)**
   - SQL adapter – Communicating with SQL database **(if using SQL to get data)**
   - JMS adapter – Communicating with JMS **(if using JMS to get data)**
   - Invoking adapter procedures from client applications **(if using Worklight Adapters)**
   - Advanced adapter usage and mashup **(if using Worklight Adapters)**
   - Using Java in adapters **(if using Java inside adapters)**
3. [Read my Answer on Debugging Worklight/JSONStore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15959984/186909)
4. Ask specific questions. Provide at least the following:

   - What your goal is. Add the use case. Add pseudocode if applicable.
   - What you tried, before the error and what you tried to solve the error. Add code if applicable.
   - What you searched for when you got the error. What you found and learned from researching the problem.
   - Operating System and Version (e.g. Windows XP SP3 Virtual Machine, Mac OSX 10.8.3)
   - Eclipse Version (e.g. Eclipse Indigo 3.7 Java EE)
   - JDK Version (e.g. Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7))
   - Worklight Version (e.g. Worklight 5.0.6 Developer Edition)
   - iOS Version (e.g. iOS Simulator 6.1, iPhone 4S iOS 6.0)
   - Android Version (e.g. Android Emulator 4.1.1, Samsung Galaxy Android 4.0 API Level 14)
   - adb Version (e.g. Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31)