# Worklight 5.0.6 JSONStore with Sync error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I try to init JSONStore Sync with Adapter in Worklight 5.0.6 like below:

```
           var usersSearchFields = {"age":"integer","name.demo":"string"},
                usersAdapterOptions = {
                    name: 'user',
                    replace: 'updateUser',
                    remove: 'deleteUser',
                    add: 'addUser',
                    load: {
                        procedure: 'getUsers',
                        params: [],
                        key: 'users'
                    },
                    accept: function (data) {
                        return (data.status === 200);
                    }
                };
                var collections = {
                        users : {
                        searchFields : usersSearchFields,
                        adapter :   usersAdapterOptions
                        }
                };
                var options = {
                        username: 'carlos', 
                        password: '123' 
                        };
                var usersCollection=WL.JSONStore.init(collections, options)
                        .then(function (res) {
                            logMessage('Collection has been initialized');      
                        })  
                        .fail(function (errobject) {
                        WL.Logger.debug(errobject.toString());
                        });
```

It runs successfully in the first time but after i exit app then return, it gets error: 
***"PROVISION_TABLE_SEARCH_FIELDS_MISMATCH"***

Anyone can help me please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the following known issue:

[PM85364: JSONSTORE ERROR AFTER FIRST LAUNCH ON ANDROID WITH '.' IN SEARCH FIELDS.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg1PM85364). To fix it upgrade to the 5.0.6.1 Fix Pack ([Source](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038650)).

Typically:

**-2 PROVISION_TABLE_SEARCH_FIELDS_MISMATCH**

You cannot change search fields without calling `destroy` or `removeCollection` and `init` or `initCollection` with the new search fields. This error can happen if you change the name or type of the search field. For example: `{key: 'string'}` to `{key: 'number'}` or `{myKey: 'string'}` to `{theKey: 'string'}`.

The documentation is [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_class_wl_jsonstore.html). I also recommend [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15959984/186909) on JSONStore debugging.

This fixes issues like the one you're facing:

> Reset the Simulator or Emulator and/or call WL.JSONStore.destroy().

Comment: but i didn't change search field value, just exit app and return, i realize that if i change search field **{"name.demo":"string"}** to **{"name":"string"}**, it wont't get this error, but "name.demo" is what i want

Comment: Your issue is explained in my answer above, specifically when I said *"or {myKey: 'string'} to {theKey: 'string'}"*. Notice "myKey" changed to "theKey". A solution was also provided in my answer above. Search fields are not dynamic and you are treating them as such.

Comment: Hi, I guess you miss understood me.
it is about naming convension of Json Store's keys.
When I use name without "." for example: "name", everything is fine.
 However, when I use "." in the key's name for example:"name.demo",
then, in the first time using application, it is fine. However, when I close my application, re-open it again
I received this error message and cannot proceed with JSon store search. Notice that i always destroy jsonstore before change searchfield's name to test.

Comment: Sorry about that, I did miss understood your message. Seems like you're running into this issue: [PM85364: JSONSTORE ERROR AFTER FIRST LAUNCH ON ANDROID WITH '.' IN SEARCH FIELDS.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg1PM85364) Try installing 'Fix Pack 5.0.6.1' ([source](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038650#5061)).

Comment: Updated answer to link to the issue.

Comment: thanks cnandreu, i have updated to worklight 5.0.6.1 and fixed this error!