# How to get/reflect deleted record from server to JSONStore?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

1. In IBM Worklight JSONStore is there is any delete Synchronization Services call which helps developers to get/retrieve delete record from server to JSONStore.
2. Do we have a privilege to custom  IBM Worklight JSONStore  library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any API which deals with dependency between entities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856386/is-there-any-api-which-deals-with-dependency-between-entities)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the recommended ways to debug Worklight applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959693/what-are-the-recommended-ways-to-debug-worklight-applications)

Answer (score 0):

(1) no
(2) JSONStore recently went open source, so you can attempt to integrate your application with that version, where you can also enhance it for your needs: https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=jsonstore

**note:** the JSONStore version that is shipped by MFP by default is not the open source version at this time, so take that under advisement.